# OpenGL only blank screen when drawing triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

This program is written in CodeBlocks. I already add options `GL` and `SDL2` to `build options -> Linker settings` . When building and running this program in `CodeBlocks` I got no errors but only saw a blank window when it should be a triangle. I also tried using command line `g++ main.cpp -o main -lGL -lSDL2 & ./main` but got the same issues. Any idea?

```
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL3/gl3.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Notre fenêtre
    SDL_Window* fenetre(0);
    SDL_GLContext contexteOpenGL(0);

    SDL_Event evenements;
    bool terminer(false);


    // Initialisation de la SDL
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Erreur lors de l'initialisation de la SDL : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();

        return -1;
    }


    // Version d'OpenGL
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);


    // Double Buffer
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);


    // Création de la fenêtre
    fenetre = SDL_CreateWindow("Test SDL 2.0", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if(fenetre == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Erreur lors de la creation de la fenetre : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();

        return -1;
    }


    // Création du contexte OpenGL
    contexteOpenGL = SDL_GL_CreateContext(fenetre);

    if(contexteOpenGL == 0)
    {
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(fenetre);
        SDL_Quit();

        return -1;
    }

    // Vertices et coordonnées
    float vertices[] = {-0.5, -0.5,   0.0, 0.5,   0.5, -0.5};


    // Boucle principale
    while(!terminer)
    {
        // Gestion des évènements

        SDL_WaitEvent(&evenements);

        if(evenements.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)
            terminer = true;


        // Nettoyage de l'écran
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // On remplie puis on active le tableau Vertex Attrib 0
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);

        // On affiche le triangle
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        // On désactive le tableau Vertex Attrib puisque l'on n'en a plus besoin
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);


        // Actualisation de la fenêtre
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(fenetre);
    }
    // On quitte la SDL

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(contexteOpenGL);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(fenetre);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is your shader?

Comment: I'm working on it. In the tutorial I took, the part of Shader comes after. But now I realize how essential it is to have Shader in my program to make it work

Answer (score 0):

The Problem could be, that `SDL_WaitEvent` waits until it receives input so it blocks the rest of your code: "Use this function to wait *indefinitely* for the next available event" (from https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEvent). Try to use something like https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent

Answer (score 0):

On my system, glGetError() is returning INVALID_OPERATION after the call to glEnableVertexAttribArray(0) from here:

```
// On remplie puis on active le tableau Vertex Attrib 0
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
```

Errors like this cause nothing to be drawn to the screen.  More info on glGetError() can be found here:

[glGetError()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetError.xml)

Also, you did not specify a shader anywhere.  You might want to consider working through a complete tutorial on how to get a triangle on the screen in OpenGL.  A comprehensive tutorial on how to do this can be found here:

https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle

Comment: Thank you so much! This would be very helpful! I have created my Shaders but still cannot make it work. Once I get the right answer I will reply to you all.